# Ignoring certain commands in the wrong vim window

Tags: vim, keyboard, buffer

It's pretty common that I'm in a quickfix, nerdtree, or other special window and  hit Ctrl-O, thinking I'm in my main window. What I'm trying to do is go back to my previous location in my main window. I tend to also make this mistake by opening up by bufexplorer in my quickfix window, and that causes some really strange problems.

Is there an easy way to ignore certain commands in certain kinds of buffers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always map certain things to `<NOP>` *(no operation)*,

for example in netrw (***:e .***)

```
nnoremap <C-o> <NOP>
"<C-o> no longer works
```

Applicability of this will, of course, depend on a case in question. Combined with Filetype and `<buffer>` in autocommands this may give good results.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, at least for nerdtree. I haven't quite gotten it to work for the quickfix window, because when the quickfix window is opened, it doesn't count as a bufenter. If I leave and re-enter the quickfix window, it works. Here's the lines from my .vimrc:

`
au BufEnter NERD_tree_* map <buffer> <C-O> <NOP>
au BufEnter NERD_tree_* map <buffer> <C-e> <NOP>

au BufEnter * call TurnOffQFCommands()
au BufEnter * call TurnOffQFCommands()
function! TurnOffQFCommands()
  if &ft=="qf"
    map <buffer> <C-O> <NOP>
    map <buffer> <C-e> <NOP>
  endif
endfunction
`

Answer (score 1):

`<C-w>p` let's you go to the previous window.

Answer (score 0):

To jump forward after jumping back you can press <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd>.

From [vim wiki - Jumping to previously visited locations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations):

> Like a web browser, you can go back, then forward:
>
> ```
>  Press Ctrl-O to jump back to the previous (older) location.
>  Press Ctrl-I (same as Tab) to jump forward to the next (newer) location.
> ```
>
> Display the jump list for the current window with:
>
> ```
> :jumps
> ```
>
> Your current location in the jump list is indicated with '>', and the
>   first number in each row is a count that can be used to jump to that
>   position. For example, after pressing Ctrl-O three times, the :jumps
>   command may show something like this:
>
> ```
>  jump line  col file/text
>    4   102    0 somefile.txt
>    3    93    0 -invalid-
>    2    23    0 the current line 23 is shown here
>    1    89   34 the current line 89 is shown here
> >  0    22   40 Display the jump list for the current window with:
>    1    39    0 the current line 39 is shown here
>    2   995    0 anotherfile.txt
>    3    53  102 the current line 53 is shown here
> ```
>
> Given the above, you could press:
>
> ```
> Ctrl-I to jump to line 39 in the current buffer.
> Ctrl-O to jump to line 89 in the current buffer.
> 4 then Ctrl-O to jump to line 102 in file somefile.txt.
> 3 then Ctrl-I to jump to line 53 in the current buffer.
> ```
>
> In the example above:   The last line was added to the jump list when
>   the first Ctrl-O was pressed (so you can return to the initial
>   position: line 53, column 102). Line 93 in the current buffer no
>   longer exists (the jump location is invalid).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I know how to go back and forth in the history. It's just that I want to ignore or redirect these commands to the proper window. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @notid Ah, my mistake.  Although, I do not *think* it is possible to remap vim commands to work across multiple windows, but I hope I'm wrong about that for your sake ).